# sometimes cannot delete row from table

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I created a local website in asp.net using objectdatasource, sometimes user want to delete the row from table the row is not deleted and the page just reload. **this happens arbitrary**. when it is deleted from phpmyadmin the operation succeed.

**the backend is mysql and the underlined table is independent.I also check the table using**

**check table table_name**

**but the status is OK.**

anybody having any clue this problem is annoying.

Comment: Show some code in question

Comment: Without seeing any code how can we solve this issue?